# Generate Access Token for SPFX SSO Azure AD using C# without prompting user(Automate)

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, spfx

I have developed SPFX application with Azure AD SSO is enabled. It is also connecting to web api using bearer token generated using ADAL OAuth2 implicit flow along with SPFX SSO access token. This is working fine.
I want to test the webapi using Postman. Currently i am copying bearer token from developer tool of browser and send it in header to connect webapi.
I want to automate the above 2 steps, so that i can do automate user testing scenario.

1.Generate AZURE AD SSO access token from C#/postman by passing user credentials. (Postman/React/C#)
2.Generate bearer token using Access Token generated from step-1.(Postman/React/C#).

I want to automate the above steps using Postman/C#/angular/react.
Kindly provide me the detailed steps to achieve the above scenario for testing.

Suresh Rajamani

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my  environment.

Open Postman --> Create a new request --> Go to Authorization --> Select Type as OAuth 2.0 --> Under Configure New Token, fill the details :

Token Name : give the token name

Grant Type : Implicit

Callback URL : redirect uri of your app registration

Auth URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Client ID : Client ID of your app registration

Scope : add scope as per the permissions  required. For ex: https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read, for  reading mails
Client Authentication : send as Basic Auth Header

[image]

Click on Get New Access Token and login with user credentials and give consent. A new Bearer Token will be generated

[image]

Click on Use Token. Now we can make any requests using that token.